# Git Confirm Before Commit

Tags: git, bash, github, git-bash

Is there a way to configure Git to give me an alert before or after I commit locally? For example, after I commit (ideally before), I get some kind of output like "Did you double check settings.py?". Alternatively, can I script this using bash? I've been looking around, but I haven't found much on the topic.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-commit hook should give you the opportunity to do what you want.

See http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hook.  The example scripts contain good documentation.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I _have_ in fact read the documentation, however, git hooks slipped my mind. Again, I did some searching around, but did not come across hooks. Isn't that the whole purpose of SO? To ask questions, right wrong or indifferent?

Comment: @AndrewSmiley - NP :) - I wavered between coding a solution and just pointing you in the right direction. this seemed like a situation where you, like me(often), just need a 'hook' to a specific in the vast ocean of doc.

Comment: actual link :https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks